# Dataflow and small datasets

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm using Cloud Dataflow to load data into Cloud SQL. Some loads consist of simple transformations on small datasets. I noticed Cloud Dataflow takes time to allocate VMs to do the processing. Is there any way to define a dedicated VM for cloud dataflow? Or does it have to start VMs each time it runs a job? Is cloud dataflow useful for small datasets or it is feasible to only use it when we have to work with big datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow can't use a dedicated VM, and updating a pipeline may take the full setup time to get going. From launching a bunch of streaming jobs I find they take ~4 minutes to start pulling from PubSub consistently. For small datasets you may find it faster to use the local runner on a GCE instance in the same region as your SQL database, on a single machine.

If you're working with small datasets and don't plan to scale realistically to very large datasets, you could likely use shell commands to process your data much faster and cheaper than running a Dataflow job.

[A great article about avoiding large data tools when you don't have large data.](https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html)